# How to conect docker nginx with express and react app on windows

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx

I found many tutorials about those but none uniting the 3 of them. I want to learn how to do that because I need to start deploying react websites I made and I wanted to deploy them on my domain and hosting on my computer for testing purposes.

In what order should I learn those to archive that ? What tutorials do you recommend ? I found some tutorials about them but got really confused with the cascade of things to learn. I got windows power shell working, did some node tutorials some express ones and managed to run nginx on docker but couldn't finish.

I am feeling ok with my css, js, and react, made a little game got some things working did some practice but now I am kind of stuck. I really appreciate any help or suggestions you can provide to keep going on my learning path.

Bellow are the video tutorials I watched :
CSS
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Rs2ND1ryYc
React 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLX62G4lc44

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a `docker-compose.yml` file to define and run multi container Docker applications. And then with a single command you can build and start all your services.You can run both Linux and Windows programs and executables in `Docker`. Docker creates thin virtual environments for your apps.
Here is an example of what you want.This is the folder structure:

```
|--client  
     |--Dockerfile
     |--components
     |--index.js
|--server
     |--Dockerfile
     |--index.js
|--nginx
     |-- Dockerfile
     |--default.conf
|--docker.compose.yml
```

`Dockerfile` for the react client:

```
FROM node:alpine as builder
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./package.json . /
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
```

`Dockerfile` for nginx

```
FROM nginx 
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

`default.conf` for nginx

```
upstream client {
    server client:3000;
}

upstream api {
    server api:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://client;
    }
    location /sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass  http://api;
    }
}
```

`Dockerfile` for node/express server

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

`docker-compose.yml` file. You can switch mongo with any database you want to use for your api.You can build and run evrything with `docker-compose up --build` from the main project directory(where the `docker-compose` file is )

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
  api:
    restart: always  
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./server
    volumes: 
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
    links:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
    links:
      - api
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have some doubts, and it might take me a while to do everything right I think.

So first i have to find some tutorials about docker compose file right ?

Does the first dockerfile have termination like dockerfile.yml or i just create a "file" name Dockerfile and paste that text ?

Webstorm have right click open in terminal so is that how i should run those commands ?

Lets see if I understand it right, i open windows power shell change directory to my app and type "docker-compose up --build" is that it ? will this create the folder structure ?

Comment: No, it will not create the folder structure. It's to build and run the `Dockerfile`s . `docker-compose` file is useful because with it you have a single entry point for all the services you want to run. You can read the docs its very easy. Here is my repo from which I took the code and slightly altered it. You can just clone it and start from there. It is a little different because there are `Dockerfile.dev`s for development phase and regular `Dockerfile`s for supposed deployment;) Here it is https://github.com/ConstantineGochev/react-docker-multi